# Deploying WAR package TOMCAT

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

I have two identical WAR files: one packaged without Maven and one packaged using Maven. When I try to deploy the Maven packaged WAR using Tomcat I get an HTTP status 404 error (The requested resource is not available) The original WAR (packed without using Maven) runs smoothly.I am sure that the WAR packaged using Maven has all the required files since it is exactly the same as the original package. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Compare the contents of both files to see if something's missing.

Comment: No matter how sure you are: If one runs and one doesn't, they're not the same. WAR files are zip files. You can just unzip them and compare the content.

Comment: do a checksum/hash (md5 or something) of both war files and compare them. check web.xml in both war files (under web-inf). Good tool for checksum use http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/

Comment: Would be nice to see your maven war configuration, share it please

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios like this I only trust tools that visualize if the bundles are really identical or not. I will show you some tools below (MS Windows tools).

**Checksum tool:**

- http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/

The tool will very quick give me a checksum of the entire bundle. And I can compare this against the other file.

**Diff tool:**

- http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

If checksum are not the same you will need see the difference in the bundles.
In this case I would use some diff tool, like kDiff.

**The web.xml - deployment descirptor**

Some files are very important and you will need to check first, like the deployment descriptor *web.xml* in the WEB-INF folder. Verify its content, the security settings, configuration of your servlets etc. The "entry" to your web service.

**Unzip and check the folders/files**

You know that your war file is a normal "zip" bundle. Just unzip it and check the content. You can deploy to your tomcat as a unzipped war (i.e. the entire folder, the folder name will be your context-root).

**Verify tomcat logs**

Check your output upon deployment and access to the web solution. Look the [tomcat logging level](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) and increase the level and watch your logs.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the war files ? If they differ, tomcat deploys them on a different context path.

Maven usually puts the version at the end for example:

myproject.war would be deployed to localhost:8080/myproject

while myproject-1.0.0.war whould be deployed to localhost:8080/myproject-1.0.0/ (Not sure if it handles the dots)

You can try to rename the war files to the same path, or ROOT.war for "/"

Have you checked the catalina.out log ?